# files not updated using tomcat and opendap thredds server

Tags: xml, tomcat

I am running operational ocean model, so I put new netCDF files every day into the folder which is served via opendap TDS and tomcat.
When model is done old files are overwritten with new ones *they have the same name(!)* but seems that server is not updating/serving new data. If I do ncdump at the system disk file I get one values; than if I use access via opendap *the same ncdump* I got different, seems to me like it is cached and hold and not refreshed as I would like.
Is there a way to disable caching of the netCDF files via TDS opendap tomcat?
Thanks,
cheers
Ivica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that the THREDDS Data Server (TDS) does not cache your data, you can set up a datasetRoot that is not cached.  Here's an actual example we use for an ocean forecast model, where new forecast NetCDF files are simply uploaded to the server every day, using the same names (here NECOFS_GOM2_FORECAST.nc, NECOFS_GOM3_FORECAST.nc, etc.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/thredds/InvCatalog/v1.0"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" name="THREDDS Catalog for NetCDF Files" version="1.0.1">

  <service name="allServices" serviceType="Compound" base="">
    <service name="ncdods" serviceType="OpenDAP" base="/thredds/dodsC/"/>
    <service name="HTTPServer" serviceType="HTTPServer" base="/thredds/fileServer/"/>
  </service>

  <datasetRoot path="FVCOM" location="/http/www/CODFISH/Data/FVCOM/" cache="false"/>

  <dataset name="NECOFS GOM2 Forecast" ID="gom2_nocache" serviceName="allServices"
    urlPath="FVCOM/NECOFS/Forecasts/NECOFS_GOM2_FORECAST.nc" dataType="Grid"/>

  <dataset name="NECOFS GOM3 Forecast" ID="gom3_nocache" serviceName="allServices"
    urlPath="FVCOM/NECOFS/Forecasts/NECOFS_GOM3_FORECAST.nc" dataType="Grid"/>

  <dataset name="NECOFS MET Forecast" ID="necofs_met" serviceName="allServices"
    urlPath="FVCOM/NECOFS/Forecasts/NECOFS_MET_FORECAST.nc" dataType="Grid"/>

  <dataset name="NECOFS GOM3 Wave Forecast" ID="necofs_gom3_wave" serviceName="allServices"
    urlPath="FVCOM/NECOFS/Forecasts/NECOFS_WAVE_FORECAST.nc" dataType="Grid"/>

  <dataset name="NECOFS MASSBAY Forecast" ID="massbay_nocache" serviceName="allServices"
    urlPath="FVCOM/NECOFS/Forecasts/NECOFS_FVCOM_OCEAN_MASSBAY_FORECAST.nc" dataType="Grid"/>

</catalog>
```

There is more information on  https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/projects/THREDDS/tech/reference/ThreddsConfigXMLFile.html, where it also says "LOOK the following may not be working" but for sure it works on TDS 4.2.9, because we are using it here: http://www.smast.umassd.edu:8080/thredds/forecasts.html

Comment: I am using THREDDS Data Server [Version 4.2.10 - 20120417.2151] and I can confirm that your way cache="false" works for me!!  Thanks!